# Post values without hidden variables and ajax?

Tags: php, post, paypal, payu

I am integrating a payment gateway with my website in php. They provided key and salt values to uniquely identify me. The sample code given by them store key and salt in hidden variables. I think it is not secure.

Now my question is, is there any way that we can pass these values to payment gateway (from mysite.com/checkout.php to paymentgateway.com page). The methods like `file_get_contents()` does work as it won't redirect to payment page.

Comment: Make a request to your php file and from this file make a request to paymentgateway.

Comment: may this one help to you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17576444/how-to-pass-paypal-api-credentials-securely-in-with-php-and-why-is-this-not-con

Comment: please set your hidden input as disabled.. thats all it will take care of your problem.
<input disabled="disabled" type="text" name="test"/>

Comment: @u_mulder can you give a little code for that? I had the same idea but could not do that!

Comment: @Anuraj P.R if we use disable fields I think, users can see the credentials through view page source. I do not even want them to see not just preventing them from modifying!